# get value of json_decode with individual name

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

how can I receive individual information from the JSON?

JSON:

```
{
   "134819":{
      "0":"WEBRip LD x264 PsO",
      "1":"1",
      "3":"134819",
      "r":{
         "t":[
            13,
            11
         ],
         "b":[
            14,
            11
         ]
      },
      "2":"WEBRip LD x264 PsO",
      "links":{
         "Streamcloud":[
            [
               "1",
               "mediabox",
               "streamcloud.ico",
               "http:\/\/streamcloud.eu\/zaxljnwu4yti\/tn-855.mkv.html",
               "81",
               "stream",
               "0"
            ]
         ],
         "Openload":[
            [
               "1",
               "redirect",
               "none",
               "https:\/\/openload.co\/f\/r9WrAB2RPdI\/tn-603.mkv",
               "123",
               "download",
               "0"
            ]
         ],
         "Share-online":[
            [
               "1",
               "redirect",
               "so.ico",
               "http:\/\/www.share-online.biz\/dl\/9HWBDGHPJ5",
               "67",
               "download",
               "1"
            ]
         ],
         "Uptobox":[
            [
               "1",
               "redirect",
               "none",
               "https:\/\/uptobox.com\/4p3yqf8bvzxv",
               "506",
               "download",
               "5"
            ]
         ],
         "Flashx":[
            [
               "1",
               "redirect",
               "none",
               "https:\/\/www.flashx.tv\/emx2759pwqef.html",
               "129",
               "stream",
               "8"
            ]
         ],
         "Oboom":[
            [
               "1",
               "redirect",
               "none",
               "https:\/\/www.oboom.com\/HPLSZNRY\/",
               "502",
               "download",
               "18"
            ]
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

This works for "0"

```
$ddlme_jason['134819'][0]
```

= WEBRip LD x264 PsO

But I want to display the blocks under "links". The name and the url.

```
      "links":{
         "Streamcloud":[
            [
               "1",
               "mediabox",
               "streamcloud.ico",
               "http:\/\/streamcloud.eu\/zaxljnwu4yti\/tn-855.mkv.html",
               "81",
               "stream",
               "0"
            ]
         ],
         "Openload":[
            [
               "1",
               "redirect",
               "none",
               "https:\/\/openload.co\/f\/r9WrAB2RPdI\/tn-603.mkv",
               "123",
               "download",
               "0"
            ]
         ],
[...more code...]
```

Ultimately, I want to output everything automatically from "links" as foreach loop!?

Site1 + Url
Site2 + Url
...
Like:

```
$site1 = "Streamcloud"
$url = "http:\/\/streamcloud.eu\/zaxljnwu4yti\/tn-855.mkv.html"
```

I don't know JSON very well yet. I would be very happy about an answer and an example and thank you in advance.

Comment: If the [0] index is "WEBRip LD x264 PsO", wouldn't you logically find what you seek at the ['links'] index?

Comment: Hello. I the receive: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\test\index.php on line 133 `$json['134819']['links']` In addition, the names and urls are individual. I wouldn't ask if I could have solved it myself. I try to do it all the time and fail.

Comment: Don't treat it as a string.  You said you wanted to loop through the links with foreach so why aren't you treating it as an array?   You may want to read the php manual a bit more on data types and learn how to debug or dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### WORKING CODE:

```
$json = '{"134819":{"0":"WEBRip LD x264 PsO","1":"1","3":"134819","r":{"t":[13,11],"b":[14,11]},"2":"WEBRip LD x264 PsO","links":{"Streamcloud":[["1","mediabox","streamcloud.ico","http:\/\/streamcloud.eu\/zaxljnwu4yti\/tn-855.mkv.html","81","stream","0"]],"Openload":[["1","redirect","none","https:\/\/openload.co\/f\/r9WrAB2RPdI\/tn-603.mkv","123","download","0"]],"Share-online":[["1","redirect","so.ico","http:\/\/www.share-online.biz\/dl\/9HWBDGHPJ5","67","download","1"]],"Uptobox":[["1","redirect","none","https:\/\/uptobox.com\/4p3yqf8bvzxv","506","download","5"]],"Flashx":[["1","redirect","none","https:\/\/www.flashx.tv\/emx2759pwqef.html","129","stream","8"]],"Oboom":[["1","redirect","none","https:\/\/www.oboom.com\/HPLSZNRY\/","502","download","18"]]}}}'

$arr = json_decode($json);
foreach(reset($arr)->links as $server => $link) {
    echo "{$server}: {$link[0][3]}<br />\n";
}
```